# Why does this handler not return anything?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I'm just starting the [ASP.NET tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page) and I don't understand why there is no return statement in the method:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Movie = await _context.Movie.ToListAsync();
}
```

Are one line methods automatically returned like arrow statements or does it have to do with the Task in ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a model that have property `Movie`. That property gets set when method `OnGetAsync` is called. So, you don't need return.

Method return type is `Task` because it has `await`. Its analogous to `void` type if it would be a sync method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return the list of `Movie`
then your function should be :

```
public async Task<List<Movie>> OnGetAsync()
{
    return await _context.Movie.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Maybe I need to go back and review C#.  In their code above Task is not a return value, it's a description like async?

Comment: I'm wondering why they declare a return value Task, but don't return anything. Why does that compile?

Comment: Task basically represents an async operation that returns a value

Comment: @user5389726598465 it Compiles becuae the return type is `void` and in your method body there is no return statement so basically the syntax suffices